# sql: group events by date range and make pagination

Tags: mysql

I have a sql table more or less like this (the date is in timestamp):

```
---+-------------------+--------------+-----------+
id | start date        | end date     | event     |
---+-------------------+--------------+-----------+
1  | 1459641600        |              |     A     |
2  | 1459900800        |  1460073600  |     B     |
3  | 1460160000        |  1460246400  |     C     |
4  | 1459641600        |  1460073600  |     D     |
5  | 1459728000        |  1460073600  |     E     |
6  | 1459641600        |  1459814400  |     F     |
---+-------------------+--------------+-----------+
```

and I would like to have an output like this:

```
**April 03**

evento A

evento D

evento F

**April 

04**

evento D

evento E

evento F

------ page 01 -----

**April 05**

evento D

evento E

evento F

**April 06**

evento B

evento D

evento E

------ page 02 -----

**April 07**

evento B

evento D

evento E


**April 08**

evento B

evento D

evento E

------ page 03 -----

**April 09**

evento C

**April 10**

evento C

------ page 04 -----
```

*that is: it is also divided into pages.*

how can I do this query in mysql?

thanks a lot!

Comment: Please show the work you have done.

Comment: Limit clause will help you on pagination. Have you tried that ?

Comment: hi Gonzalo! yes, but I was grouping by ID... I dont know how to group by date range for split into pages correctly... thanks